# Android not stretching layout by its own in landscape mode

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to place two images in landscape mode since my app will be in landscape mode through out. When I am doing this following code android works proper in potrait mode but in landscape mode it doest stretch with the ratio but they remains unchanged. WHat should i do it to make it handle by android

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

       <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"

            android:src="@drawable/hud" />


    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/bg" />


    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Not related, but you shouldn't mix `fill_parent` and `match_parent`.  Use `fill_parent` if you're targeting API's for 1.6+.  Use `match_parent` if you're targeting API's for 2.1+.

Comment: use LinearLayout instead of FrameLayout then you should also use android:layout_weight="1" for better understanding look [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-linearlayout.html)

Comment: What you want to do ? Do you want to fix the Layout in Landscape mode ? or want to do anything else with the ImageView ?

Comment: for Best Practice use wrap_content for ImageView width and height.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your app to always be in landscape mode, set it in the Manifest file like this:

```
<activity android:screenOrientation="landscape">
```

Then, instead of using XML to make your layout, do it from the activity. Then you can use this code to get the display size info:

```
/* First, get the Display from the WindowManager */
Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();

/* Now we can retrieve all display-related infos */
int width = display.getWidth();
```

Then you can use this display width to set the width of your images (i.e. width/2).

Answer (score 0):

You probably need android:scaleType="fitCenter" on your ImageViews.